# No debugging with VS code for React Native app (expo) possible

Tags: ios, react-native, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm currently programming a React Native app (expo) with Visual Studio Code.
For testing I'm using the iOS simulator. 
Until now the setup has worked fine. But now I have a problem with debugging my application. When I want to create a new `launch.json` file, there is no React Native environment in the dropdown list (see picture below).

[image]

I already tried to manually add the launch.json file. But when I want to add a configuration there is also no React Native entry available.

Can anyone please help me?

For debugging I installed the *React Native Tools* Extension (I also tried differnet versions).

*Version Info:*
macOS Big Sure: 11.3.1 
VS Code: 1.61.2 
React Native Tools: 1.7.1

Answer (score 0):

The best way for debugging react-native applications is using a react-native-debugger tool, check out the link below for installation and get started with this amazing community-driven tool:
[React-Native-Debugger](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger)

Comment: Thanks for your help, that would be an option. But I would still be interested in why it does not work. 
I noticed that there is a React Native environment in my VS code on my Windows PC.